# Starting an executable and passing arguments

Tags: c#, command, executable

I have definitely done something like this before, but something is not working right and I'm not 100% sure what it is.

I have an executable `executable.exe` that takes a file, does some magic and outputs a second file somewhere else. So when I run this executable via CMD, all I need to do is pass `"path1"` and `"path2"`. I put the paths in quotations because they may have spaces.

Anyway, so what I'm doing in my c# application is something like:

```
public void methodToRunExecutable()
{
var exePath = "\""+ "C:\\SomePathToAnExecutable" + "\"";
var firstFilePath = "C:\\PathToFirstFile\\NameOfFile.txt"
var secondFilePath= "C:\\PathToSecondFile\\NameOfFile.txt"

Process.Start(exePath, "\""firstFilePath + "\" \"" + secondFilePath+"\"")
}
```

However, I notice when I'm debugging is that the `"\""` is actually showing up as `\"`, like the backslash isn't escaping the quotation mark.

To be clear, when I run the CMD exe all I have to do is:

```
"C:\\PathToFirstFile\\NameOfFile.txt" "C:\\PathToSecondFile\\NameOfFile.txt"
```

and it works great. Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is it because the `"` is not being escaped?

Comment: Even despite of what Bob Horn says (though I definetely agree with him) your code should work. What's not working actually? Do all paths really exist?

Comment: `"` is shown like `\"` while debugging, but it does not prevent code from doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping is ugly and error prone. Use `@` and you won't need to escape:

```
var firstFilePath = @"C:\PathToFirstFile\NameOfFile.txt"
```

It might also be easier to use `Process` this way:

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // args here
    process.Start();
}
```